# ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{' (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging, error

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

library Address {
 
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
        // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
        // for accounts without code, i.e. `keccak256('')`
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }

 
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls, avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
```

Hi, please, advise me what is creating this error:)

> **ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{' (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }(""); ^**

Comment: Other than a missing `}` at the end of your code, this compiles successfully.

Comment: BTW, this library is already publicly available (and thoroughly tested) in [OpenZeppelin GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol), so you may as well use it rather than reinventing the wheel.